# Similar matrices that are not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

> Let $f:R^3 \to R^3$ be a function which matrix with respect to the standard basis is:
>   $$
> A = \begin{pmatrix}
>         -4 & -8 & 8 \\
>         1 & 2 & -2 \\
>         -1 & -2 & 2 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Then:
>   $$
> B = \begin{pmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & 1 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find an invertible matrix $S$ such that $ A = SBS^{-1}$. Is that matrix unique?

The teacher said that if $A$ and $B$ are similar then they have the same characteristic polynomial and therefore the same eigenvalues. 
So if the diagonal matrix of $A$ is $ D_A = H_1^{-1}AH_1$ and the diagonal matrix of $B$ is $ D_B = H_2^{-1}BH_2$ I have:

$ D_B = D_A $ so $H_2^{-1}BH_2 = H_1^{-1}AH_1$
from which:
$ H_1H_2^{-1}BH_2H_1^{-1} = A $
So the matrix $ S$ is:

$ S = H_1H_2^{-1}$

> My problem is that the matrices $A,B$ can not be diagonalized so how do I find the matrices $ H_1$ and $H_2$ ?

From what I found online this problem should be related to Jordan but we did't study it so I should solve it without Jordan.

Comment: You can replace $S$ by $-S$ hence the matrix is not unique.

Comment: Find matrices $H_1$ and $H_2$ that do what?

Comment: To calculate $S$

Comment: Without using the jordan normal form, the problem will be difficult.

Comment: @user144037: write $AS=SB$, nine equations in nine unknowns (the matrix elements of $S$).

Comment: I have been able to solve it by writing $AS = SB$ and then I solved the system but it is very long because I have 9 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Be_3=e_1$, $Be_1=Be_2=0$.
Pick a "random" vector such as $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and let $v_1=Av_3=\begin{pmatrix}-4\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then verify $Av_1=0$ and pick an independant $v_2$ in $\ker A$, for example $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $B$ represents, with respect to the basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$, the same linear map as does $A$ with respect to the standard basis. Let $S=\begin{pmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4&0&1\\1&1&0\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then 
$$ SB=\begin{pmatrix}-4&0&1\\1&1&0\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-4\\0&0&1\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$ AS = \begin{pmatrix}-4&-8&8\\1&2&-2\\-1&-2&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-4&0&1\\1&1&0\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-4\\0&0&1\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence $A=SBS^{-1}$.

Regarding uniqueness or not: note that *almost* any vector could be chosen for $v_3$ and also many different choices for $v_2$ would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning uniqueness, we have that 
$$ 
SBS^{-1} = T B T^{-1}
$$
if and only if $S^{-1} T$ centralizes $B$.

Now [a classical theorem of Frobenius](http://books.google.it/books?id=m8h9iXRRaPAC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=frobenius%20dimension%20centralizer%20matrix&source=bl&ots=8TFghUa7kn&sig=MhFn-JDIOBMvnYla-3Qp4lRxj3o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=crSxU_q0CYbe7Aaq1YG4CA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=frobenius%20dimension%20centralizer%20matrix&f=false) tells us that the centralizer of $B$ in the ring of all $3 \times 3$ matrices has dimension $5$, and thus its generic element is easily seen to be of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & e & c\\
0 & b & f\\
0 & 0 & a\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
for arbitrary $a, b, c, d, e, f$.

Clearly such a matrix is invertible when $a \ne 0 \ne b$.

So once you have found an $S$ such that 
$$ A = SBS^{-1},$$
then any $T$ of the form 
$$
T = S \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & e & c\\
0 & b & f\\
0 & 0 & a\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $ab \ne 0$, will also do the job.